# fill in sparse dates Year/Month in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I have such a table and need to fill in the missing dates on monthly level, there is a real date which is truncated to the 1st of the month. There could be more rows with other years till 2025 but I need to fill just the missing months in a year and not generate others years as well, that means the part xxx has volume in 2023 but all months are present,  so the year is full and no scaffolding for years 2023 and 2024 is needed . On the other hand part abc has sparse data in years 2023 and 2024 so I need to fill the months in both years. Where months are missing the volume will be zero.
Bear in mind the type column. Generate all months in a year for type A and for type B separately.

| type | year | month | yearmonth | datum | part | car | brand | plant | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023 | 11 | 202311 | 1.11.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 17 |
| B | 2023 | 11 | 202311 | 1.11.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 340 |
| B | 2023 | 12 | 202312 | 1.12.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 600 |
| A | 2023 | 12 | 202312 | 1.12.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 118 |
| B | 2023 | 8 | 202308 | 1.8.2023 | part abc | Polo | Volkswagen | Wolfsburg | 1 |
| A | 2023 | 8 | 202308 | 1.8.2023 | part abc | Polo | Volkswagen | Wolfsburg | 1 |
| A | 2024 | 2 | 202302 | 1.2.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 30 |
| A | 2024 | 3 | 202303 | 1.3.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 56 |
| A | 2024 | 4 | 202304 | 1.4.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 65 |
| A | 2024 | 7 | 202307 | 1.7.2023 | part abc | Q5 | Audi | Wolfsburg | 234 |
| A | 2024 | 8 | 202308 | 1.8.2023 | part abc | Polo | Volkswagen | Wolfsburg | 2 |
| A | 2024 | 11 | 202311 | 1.11.2023 | part abc | Polo | Volkswagen | Wolfsburg | 2 |
| A | 2023 | 1 | 202301 | 1.1.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 20 |
| A | 2023 | 2 | 202302 | 1.2.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 40 |
| A | 2023 | 3 | 202303 | 1.3.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 36 |
| A | 2023 | 4 | 202304 | 1.4.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 897 |
| A | 2023 | 5 | 202305 | 1.5.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 443 |
| A | 2023 | 6 | 202306 | 1.6.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 468 |
| A | 2023 | 7 | 202307 | 1.7.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 90 |
| A | 2023 | 8 | 202308 | 1.8.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 7 |
| A | 2023 | 9 | 202309 | 1.9.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 43 |
| A | 2023 | 10 | 202310 | 1.10.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 2 |
| A | 2023 | 11 | 202311 | 1.11.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 12 |
| A | 2023 | 12 | 202312 | 1.12.2023 | part xxx | Q7 | Audi | Bratislava | 3 |
| B | 2023 | 1 | 202301 | 1.1.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 20 |
| B | 2023 | 2 | 202302 | 1.2.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 40 |
| B | 2023 | 3 | 202303 | 1.3.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 36 |
| B | 2023 | 4 | 202304 | 1.4.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 897 |
| B | 2023 | 5 | 202305 | 1.5.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 443 |
| B | 2023 | 6 | 202306 | 1.6.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 468 |
| B | 2023 | 7 | 202307 | 1.7.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 90 |
| B | 2023 | 8 | 202308 | 1.8.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 7 |
| B | 2023 | 9 | 202309 | 1.9.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 43 |
| B | 2023 | 10 | 202310 | 1.10.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 2 |
| B | 2023 | 11 | 202311 | 1.11.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 12 |
| B | 2023 | 12 | 202312 | 1.12.2023 | part xxx | Up | Volkswagen | Bratislava | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`.

Your requirements are very difficult to follow; so, if you have the simplified sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c, ym) AS
SELECT 1, 1,  1, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2,  2, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1,  3, DATE '2023-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2,  4, DATE '2023-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2,  6, DATE '2023-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2,  8, DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 10, DATE '2023-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 12, DATE '2023-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,  1, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2,  6, DATE '2023-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,  7, DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2,  8, DATE '2023-04-01' FROM DUAL;
```

And for each `a` and `b` you want to generate all the months for the first 6 months of 2023 and generate a value for `c` of `0` for the missing rows then you can use:

```sql
SELECT t.a,
       t.b,
       COALESCE(t.c, 0) AS c,
       c.ym
FROM   (
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2023-01-01', LEVEL - 1) AS ym
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.a, t.b)
       ON (t.ym = c.ym)
```

Outputs:

| A | B | C | YM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 |

Take the same technique and apply it to your data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zgVKSKHJ)

Comment: almost there. add new row for exaple  2,2,20,2024-01-01. the output should be full year where at least one month is present not 6 months . So I can user 24 instead of 6 but I don't want it for every a,b combination. in this case just conbination 2,2 has at least 1 month in 2023 and 2024 that means just this combination gets new rows for full year 2024 the others in 2023 only

Comment: @Pato As stated in the answer, your requirements are not well defined or easy to decipher so this is a demonstration of a technique that can be used and you will need to adapt it to your requirements.

Comment: you did good job and I commented that ehat is needed. your output is almoat fine,just need to update your data with one row as in my previous comment with the desired output. you have to add missing month for each year but only for those combination that has at least one month in a year..you added just 6 month. I want all 12 months. If there are data in 2024 then 12 months as well. When I use 24 in connect by clause it will generate 24 month but not all combinations of a,b have data for2 years

Comment: I created new requirements, hope this is more clear   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203766/generate-dates-on-monthly-level-in-oracle-sql